# How to instantiate an object from an arraylist that holds multiple object types

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I am creating a piece of software as part of a graded assignment. In the program there is a parent class **User**, with three child classes **Employee**, **ShopOwner**, and **Customer**.

```
public class UserList {

ArrayList<User>Users;    

public UserList(){
Users=new ArrayList<>();
}
```

When the program starts the objects are instantiated and added to **UserList**, an ArrayList that should hold **User** objects, including its child classes:

```
public void loadFromFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{


FileReader reader;
reader = new FileReader(filename);
BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(reader);
String record = new String();

while ((record = bin.readLine())!=null)
   {    
            String Name = bin.readLine();
            String Password = bin.readLine();
            String Role = bin.readLine();

            switch (Role){

                case "Customer":
                   Customer customer = new Customer();
                   customer.edit(Name, Password, Role);
                   add(customer);
                   break;

                case "Employee":
                   Employee employee = new Employee();
                   employee.edit(Name, Password, Role);
                   add(employee);                    
                   break;  

                case "ShopOwner":
                   ShopOwner shopOwner = new ShopOwner();
                   shopOwner.edit(Name, Password, Role);
                   add(shopOwner);                      
                   break;             
           }  
   }

bin.close();
bin =null;

}
```

the add method is as follows:

```
public void add(User src) throws IOException{

Users.add (src);
```

}

At this point I expect that **Users**, the ArrayList of type **User**, can contain instances of all three child classes.

In my main method I need to initialise an object to access the methods of child class **Customer**, this is where things are becoming difficult, I have the following customer object instantiated:

```
aCustomer = new Customer();
```

I then try and assign values to it using a method in the UserList Class:

```
aCustomer = theUserList.logIn(name,password,role);
```

the logIn method is as follows:

```
public User logIn(String strname, String strpassword, String strrole){   
    User currentUser = null;
    for( User aUser:this.Users)

    if(strname.equalsIgnoreCase(aUser.getName())&&
       strpassword.equalsIgnoreCase(aUser.getPassword())&&
       strrole.equalsIgnoreCase(aUser.getRole())){       

       currentUser=aUser;
    }    
return currentUser;
```

}

I realise it returns a **User** object, whereas the request is to instantiate a **Customer** object, however I am confused the logIn method is scanning through **Users**, which should hold all three object types, according to the loadFromFile() method.

The error is as follows:

[image]

I need access to the customer object in the main method. Not sure what part of the journey is wrong this is why all of it has been copied, so apologies for the long winded question. Any help pointing out the change required to access the customer object from the ArrayList containing multiple object types is very much appreciated.

I am new to Java so apologies if this is a novice question, please guide me on how to change the question if need be instead of closing it as this project is really important and I really need the help.

EDIT*

Downcasting has been used to attempt to solve this challenge, and the incompatible type error has disappeared, but the object is still not accessing the customer method getBasket().

```
User aCustomer = new Customer();
                aCustomer = theUserList.logIn(name,password,role);
                aCustomer.getBasket();
```

Comment: You may need to do downcasting or upcasting.

Comment: I have used down casting however I still cannot access the methods in class customer, still only class user. please see the edit for details

Answer (score 0):

Cast your return object from login function to User type

```
switch (role)
        {
            case "Customer":
                Customer acustomer = (Customer) userList.logIn("A","B","C");
                //System.out.println(acustomer.Name);


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved by downcasting. on the following line of code aCustomer is initially an object of type User, it then gets downcasted to type Customer.

```
aCustomer = theUserList.logIn(name,password,role);   

 Customer castedCustomer = (Customer)aCustomer;
try {
    castedCustomer.getTheBasket().add(aProduct);



} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ShopJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Thank you for your help with this all.